# Clone product display with referenced product

Tags: commerce, rules

I am using Commerce Kickstart for Drupal 7, and I need to be able to clone products.

In Commerce Kickstart you have all the products just as "reference" of node, product display. I mean, the products themselves are displayed for customers similar like any other page, with "attached" actual products. (this allows you to create more variations of one type)

I am trying to clone both of those by one operation - to clone Product display (as node), and also referenced product by this product display. But when I used basic Node Clone module, it just clones Product display as a node but not the reference. Result is, the same cloned content with "attached" reference product at the very bottom, but when I change that product, It also changes the product of previously cloned product display.

Here is what I mean: http://harmonel.sk/stuff/drupal_commerce.jpg

I am not sure what to do, I am not very good with coding, maybe I should somehow re-write the Node Clone module to also clone the referenced product? Does anyone had similar or same problem? I am trying to achieve this with Rules but with no success, but maybe that would be the best way to achieve this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try  https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate  and https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate_commerce

The Node Clone module focus on cloning using the administration interface and is designed only for nodes replication, whereas Replicate can clone any entities (nodes, taxonomy terms, users, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did installed both of those modules, but I still do not get the usage. Can you please point me a bit more to right direction? How should I start? I have been writing custom codes in many web languages for years, but I am newbie in drupal, and it works a lot more different than custom plain php. I get it I have to write to template.php or write custom module, but I do not know how to do this. Would it be possible to execute custom php by rules? "after node is cloned"? Would not it be simpler?